# Angular - component style sheet not working with dynamically created elements by external js file

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular8, alertifyjs

I have a component that uses alertify file. I am trying to change the background colour of the success message popup. It is not working.

`.alertify-notifier .ajs-message.ajs-success{
    background-color: #00cccc;
}`

```
:host ::ng-deep div.alertify-notifier .ajs-message.ajs-success.ajs-visible {
color: #fff;
background-color: #00cccc;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
border-radius: 10px;}
```

I can see the popup with standard colours, the CSS is not working even with ng-deep. Please suggest how I can change the styles of this dynamic control created by the alertifyjs.

Comment: Browsers use [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) when they find conflicting CSS to know which piece should win. Without seeing the CSS where the original colours are set, we can't tell what the solution is, but take a look at this link so you can determine if your CSS "wins" over the default CSS.

Comment: Angular uses view encapsulation for CSS you may need to put it in root css and not in component.

Comment: @JohnPeters this works. However,this will change the style of all the popups

Comment: There's an angular.json option to take down view encapulation. Plus you may also need the :root. Pseudo selector.

Comment: I want my styles to be applied only to one element. I don't want others to be affected.this option affects the other popups too.